# how to iterate through an object's list?

Tags: java, design-patterns, iterator

I'm currently facing this problem in Java, lets say I have a class `ListOfTasks`:

```
public class ListOfTasks {
    private Point startingPoint;
    ArrayList<Task> tasks;
}
```

In another class, I want to iterate through the array list `tasks` directly by calling ListOfTasks, and not by retrieving tasks first and then iterate through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many ways to do that:--

Write GETTER/SETTER inside ListOfTasks POJO.

```
public class ListOfTasks {
    private Point startingPoint;
    ArrayList<Task> tasks = new  ArrayList<>();

    GETTER/SETTER
}
```

then

```
ListOfTasks list = new ListOfTasks();

for(int i=0 ;i<list.getTask().size();i++){

list.getTasks().get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by implementing [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html) to return the iterator of the array list:

```java
public class ListOfTasks implements Iterable<Task> {
    private Point startingPoint;
    ArrayList<Task> tasks;

    public Iterator<Task> iterator() {
        return tasks != null ? tasks.iterator() : Collections.emptyIterator();
    }
}
```

You can then iterate using a for-each

```java
ListOfTasks list = new ListOfTasks();
// add some tasks, etc...

for (Task task : list) {
    // use task
}

// or

list.forEach(task -> {
    // use task
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if I understand your question:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < listOfTasksObject.tasks.size(); i++) {
    Task task = listOfTasksObjects.tasks.get(i);
    // Now you can work with task...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach you are taking is wrong, because the responsibility of the property "tasks" is owned by the class ListOfTasks.

So you have to change the approach, and iterate through the set of ListOfTasks instances you have in the other class and call a method, let's say

```
public Task findTask() {
     // do something here to find the Task you were looking for, or return null
}
```

so the other class should look like this:

```
List<ListOfTasks> lists = new ArrayList<>();
// populate list here ...
Task found = lists.stream().filter(x => x.findTask()).filter(x => x != null).findAny().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just dont expose getter for tasks.
create a method in ListOfTasks class like :

```
public Task get(int index){
    return list.get(index);
}
public int size(){
    return list.size();
}
```

now use ListOfTasks like this

```
for(int i=0 ;i<listOfTasks.size();i++){

    // now access Task like this
    listOfTasks.get(i);
}
```